# How to wait for Observable's onComplete() in flatMap()

Tags: rx-java

I have an `Observable` who reads data from a database. If data is `null` I need to get it from the network. So I do `flatMap` on first `Observable`, check the result of the database operation and if it is `null` I start that another `Observable` to fetch data from the network.

**Note:** `Observable`s have different `Subscriber`s because I have different postprocessing depending on where data comes from (such a logic).

```
 Observable.just(readDataFromDb()).flatMap(new Func1<SomeData, Observable<String>>() {
        @Override public Observable<SomeData> call(SomeData s) {
          if (s == null) {
            getReadFromNetworkObservable().subscribe(new AnotherSubscriber()); // this one might not complete
            return Observable.empty(); // I think I need to send this one only after readFromNetwork() completed
          } else {
            return Observable.just(s);
          }
        }
      }).subscribe(new SomeSubscirber());
```

Given I send `Observable.empty()` to exclude data processing for `SomeSubscriber`, I have a foreboding my second `Observable` can not always be finished because it might be simply garbage collected. I guess I saw it during my tests.

At this point, I think I just need to wait until `Observable` who reads from the network completed and then send `Observable.empty()`. So can I make the execution synchronous? But still I have a feeling I do it wrong.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939175/rxjava-and-cached-data and this blog http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/ . Also check `doOnNext` operator from RxJava to get some ideas.

Comment: You can take a look on my question where I discovered several options to combine data from multiple sources. With community help we get the most robust version for this use case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797144/andorid-rxjava-how-to-get-data-from-cache-and-and-the-same-time-update-it-in-th

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make any observable as blocking with `.toBlocking` shortcut (See full info https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators)

```java
Data d = getReadFromNetworkObservable()
            .toBlocking()
            .first() //  or single() or singleOrDefault()

// manipulate with data here
```

Combining cache with network data is described here: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/

And here: [RxJava and Cached Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939175/rxjava-and-cached-data)

Comment: What's the difference between those two?

Comment: They are the same to illustrate a point: there is no way `AnotherSubscriber` or lines below it could be called earlier than readDataFromNetwork returns a data result.

Comment: I see. I've just realized I added confusion with `just()` operator. It is actually just an `Observer`. I've updated a question.

Comment: Ok. Use `toBlocking` then. Also check that article describing more "natural" way to accomplish the task.

Comment: I'm afraid in this case I can't use my Subsribers.

Comment: Subscribers are callbacks. Callbacks are designed for handling results of asynchronous calls. You want the opposite - synchronous call. If you must use subscriber callback try to play with `Schedulers.immediate` but make sure, that your Observable returns only single result or explicitly calls `onComplete` or you will block the thread forever.